# python call while using form to post something into sqlite database

Tags: python, django, django-templates

how can we call the python without the help of any framework like django ?? is it possible without any framework like django?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="textareastyle.css">
<title>
Blog site
</title>
</head>
<body><br/>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
</script><br/>
<form action= '{% url my_view_name%}' method="POST"><br/>
<h1>Blog TITLE</h1>
<textarea name="BlogTitle" rows="1" maxlength="200" cols="100" value="BlogTitle"></textarea><br/><br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<h1>Blog Text</h1>
<textarea name="BlogText" rows="15" maxlength="1000" cols="100" value="BlogText"></textarea><br/><br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value=" Submit "/>
<br/><br/>
</form
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Well, Python is a standalone, general purpose language, so yes, you can run Python without the help of any libraries or frameworks that are built on top (be it 'online' or 'offline'). Yet, to be able to help, you have to give a bit more details as to what your exact problem is. Are you trying to do a server side form submission?

Comment: yes exactly i want to submit a form to inputs into a db using python. can you  help me with this i have used this till now

Comment: I think Forbidden Overseer did a good job at nudging you in the right direction. Start by reading the links he provided and to learn more about making Python interface with the web (using Flask, Django, Bottle, WebPy, native, ...) and learn about concepts such as WSGI and HTTP. Not forgetting about databases, security, routing, sessions, ... . It's a fun packaged journey...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, you can do it :-)  To handle form parameters use https://docs.python.org/2/library/cgi.html. To save data use https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html

These modules are standard python libraries, so you don't need to install any frameworks.

Comment: @NavinDalal: On second thought, I think you should read this if you're going this way: https://docs.python.org/2/howto/webservers.html

Answer (score 0):

What you have there is a template file (possibly written in Django template language), that works in Django (and other frameworks). That file in itself can't do form posting or stuff like that, because things like `{% url my_view_name%}` can't be understood by the browser.

Here, `{% url my_view_name%}` is an example of a built-in [template tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#url) that gets replaced with some 'data' later. Read more about [Django templating language](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/templates/) to understand how this templates work, and also go through Django [tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/intro/tutorial01/) if possible. This will give you an idea about how the framework works in general.

Once you understand that, you should know that there are other templating systems available, like [Jinja2](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/) and you can use these templating languages with any Python framework of your choice like Django or [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/). Read more about this [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#configuring-the-template-system-in-standalone-mode) and [here](http://maximebf.com/blog/2012/10/building-websites-in-python-with-flask/). All these frameworks have pretty good integration with sqlite database, which you can use to post data into your database.

Comment: that very helpful but what if i don'nt want to use a framework right now ? can i do this without using a framework?

Comment: that very helpful but what if i don'nt want to use a framework right now ? can i do this without using a framework?can u guide me how to do it without framework because i got something to do without framework.

Comment: @NavinDalal: I think it's best to choose a framework and learn it at this stage - Not to build anything of importance, but to understand how the parts work together. Python Frameworks are not too hard to learn, as you can always see how they work on Github. Once you get that, you can probably hack up some new "custom framework" by putting all the parts together (the parts being various components like server etc.).